# typeguard keeps giving me errors

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript.
I still have errors after writing the type guard (and adding ?: ) for the code below. Is the syntax correct or do I need to modify the tsconfig file?.

```
interface Bird {
  type: "bird";
  speed: number;
  flyingSpeed?: number;
}
interface Snail {
  type: "snail";
  speed: number;
  crawlingSpeed?: number;
}

function accelerateAnimal(animal: Snail | Bird): void {
  switch (animal.type) {
    case "bird":
      speed = speed + animal.flyingSpeed;
      break;
    case "snail":
      speed = speed + animal.crawlingSpeed;
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}
accelerateAnimal({type: "bird", speed: 0, flyingSpeed: 3});
```

Comment: Your code snippet is invalid, there is no variable `speed`, please include it

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including the details of any error you are receiving and making sure that you don't have any typos or problems unrelated to your issue. Do you mean `animal.speed`? And I can *guess* that the issue is not with the type guard but with `?:`, which means a property is optional and possibly undefined... so you have to decide: what do I add if it's undefined? Does that mean `0`? I can fix a bunch of issues to get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NDdrRN) but you should improve the post so that such a response would be an answer to a single well-defined question.

Answer (score 4):

`flyingSpeed?: number;` marks the `flyingSpeed` property as [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties), which allows it to hold the value `undefined`. TypeScript prevents you from adding `undefined` to a number, so `speed = speed + animal.flyingSpeed;` is an error.

Either don't make the property optional or handle the undefined case explicitly. The latter can be done with nullish coalescing to treat `undefined` as `0`:

```
speed += animal.flyingSpeed ?? 0;
// speed doesn't exist in the code posted
// use animal.speed to modify the property on the passed in object
```